# Angular2 ng build --prod error Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, build

I just started with Angular2, this is my first project.
https://github.com/Exlord/angular2-sample-dynamicform

This works fine in dev but when i try `ng build --prod`, I am getting this error : `ERROR in ng:///E:/www/ng2-sample/src/app/field/field-form/field-form.component.html (2,26): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

The error refers to [this line](https://github.com/Exlord/angular2-sample-dynamicform/blob/master/src/app/field/field-form/field-form.component.html#L2)

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!form.get('name').valid && form.get('name').touched}">
```

I installed angular2+cli couple of days ago so I think everything is up to date.

What am I missing? what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error here

```
if (('ngSubmit' === en)) {
  const pd_2:any = ((<any>_co.save(_co.form.value,_co.form.valid)) !== false); <= this line
  ad = (pd_2 && ad);
}
```

It is from

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save(form.value, form.valid)" novalidate>
```

and if you open **field-form.component.ts** file

```
save(value: any): void {
  this.submitted = true;
  this.fieldService.save(<Field>value).then((field) => {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.form.reset();
    this.onSave.emit();
  });
}
```

You can notice that `save` method has only one argument while you are passing two in template

Answer (score 0):

try to add FormBuilder and FieldService at component providers.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-field-form',
  templateUrl: './field-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./field-form.component.css'],
  providers : [FormBuilder, FieldService]
})
```